# UISearchBar translucency at iOS SKD 9.3

Tags: ios, swift, ios9.3

After updating Xcode to 7.3 (iOS SDK 9.3) my `UISearchBar` ignores setting `transluent` property. This code worked well before update.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("viewDidLoad: \(searchBar.translucent)")
    searchBar.translucent = false
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    searchBar.translucent = false
    print("viewWillAppear: \(searchBar.translucent)")
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    searchBar.translucent = false
    print("viewDidAppear: \(searchBar.translucent)")
}
```

Now this code prints

> viewDidLoad: true
>
> viewWillAppear: true
>
> viewDidAppear: true

My `UISearchBar` has default search style